# Why does the division of two finite numbers returns zero?

Tags: matlab

This is my MATLAB code:

```
mu_n = Tnume_mu/Tdeno_mu;
```

When I am running this, it is showing 0 always, although variable `Tnume_mu = 255` and `Tdeno_mu = 1.7957e4`.

Comment: are you sure both are numeric?

Comment: yes sir both are numeric but I am not getting the ans.

Comment: @Neha - sorry that your question got closed that fast. In my eyes its a justified question, which shouldn't be downvoted (apart from your really bad title in the beginning). I vote for reopen, because the answer is not trivial, at least in case of matlab where one usually deals with doubles and not with int.

Comment: @thewaywewalk In that case: edit the question to make it clear he divides *integers* and not the default *doubles*. That's probably why this question attracted so many down votes.

Answer (score 6):

Have you checked the class of your variables?

```
>> x = int32(5);
>> y = int32(10);
>> class(x)
int32
>> class(y)
int32
>> x / y
0
```

but

```
>> x = 5;
>> y = 10;
>> class(x)
double
>> class(y)
double
>> x / y
0.5
```

Integer variables (`int8`, `int16`, `int32`, `int64`) can only take whole number values, and they are rounded toward zero during division, so if the result would be between 0 and 1, then 0 will be the result.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify matters I'll use easier variables names and numbers:

```
A = 5;
B = 2;
C = A/B;
C = 
   2.5
```

The `/` operator is a short cut for [`rdivide`](http://mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ref/rdivide.html). This is a regular division between two scalars. You can expand this to matrices, e.g.

```
A = magic(2);
B = magic(2).';
C = A./B;
C =

    1.0000    0.7500
    1.3333    1.0000
```

where the `./` makes sure you divide *element wise*.

There's also another division, namely the *left*-divide: [`ldivide`](http://mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ref/ldivide.html), or in short `\`. This is a specific MATLAB operator which Does the matrix multiplication commonly denoted by `C = A^-1 * B`, where `A^-1` is the inverse of matrix `A`. The beauty of this operator is that it does not *explicitly*  calculate the inverse, but rather the ****** decomposition of it, making it faster and robuster. This is not a problem, since you rarely require the explicit inverse of a matrix, which you can create by [`inv`](http://mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ref/inv.html):

```
C=A\B

C =

    0.7000   -0.2000
    0.1000    1.4000

D = inv(A)*B;
C == D
     1
```

Comment: This does absolutely not answer the question.

Comment: Well, it does tell you how to divide two numbers

Comment: I suspect is strongly has to do with the data types though this is good to keep in mind.

Comment: But the OP seems to know how to divide numbers, he does it and he doesn't get the result he expected. For me the question is clear and justified (I don't understand the downvotes actually). Your answer, is not related to the OPs problem. In your chosen examples you never get zero.